# Understanding symbols in ER diagram

Tags: entity-relationship

I need to understand the various symbols which are used in ER diagrams. For example, I saw below ER diagram in the net:

[image]

There are many symbols used in this diagram which I am not aware of. Is there any good material where I can gain clarity on what the meaning of there symbols are?

Answer (score 3):

These are Crow's Feet Notation. Use to show the relation between entities.

[Crow's Feet Notation](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Ebernatja/crowsfoot.html)

**Link Description**

Crow's Feet Notation Symbol with Description.

Answer (score 1):

First google result : [ER Diagram Symbols And Meaning](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning)